# Java exec command prompt more than one line of command

Tags: java, command-prompt

I have code like this :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("C:\\test\\MyJavaApp\\winsw\\test.exe install"); // executed
rt.exec("C:\\test\\MyJavaApp\\winsw\\test.exe start"); // not executed
```

How to execute the second line command too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("C:\\test\\MyJavaApp\\winsw\\test.exe install").waitFor();
rt.exec("C:\\test\\MyJavaApp\\winsw\\test.exe start");
```

because according to the javadoc this will be executed in a seperate process so the rt.exec() method immediatly returns without waiting.

> public Process exec(String command) throws IOException 
>   Executes the specified string command in a separate process.